# How do you create a button in ArcGIS and have it run code?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcmap, vba, java

I'm brand new to ArcGIS and have only a year or two of programming experience. I know Java and a little C#. I have a Java app that processes geographical data. I need to have a button in ArcMap that, when you click it, sends map data to this Java app.

This task was already implemented in VBA; it's my job to translate it to something else since VBA is no longer supported in ArcGIS. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

I'm not sure where to begin. I'm guessing either using the embedded Python console or the ArcObjects SDK for Java or .NET. Just want to see what someone with experience would recommend.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do this using Python now in ArcGIS 10.1.  Have a look at [Python Add-Ins](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_Python_add_in/014p00000025000000/).  You will also want to look at [Creating a Python Add-In Button](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/button/014p0000001z000000/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Are Python Add-Ins new to ArcGIS 10.1? I'm working with 10.0.

Comment: Yes, they are new in 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

Never a bad idea to start with the help and go from there: [Developing with ArcGIS](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Developing_with_ArcGIS/0001000001ww000000/)

At 10.0 you can create add-ins in either [Java](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#//00010000042z000000) or [.NET](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000w2000000). These are simpler to deploy than traditional COM components, although those are sometimes necessary for some types of projects (See [Extending ArcObjects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Extending_ArcObjects/0001000004qv000000/) for examples).

Comment: Great, thank you! Are you familiar with using Java for add-ins? I was trying to setup the ArcGIS stuff for Eclipse but I hit a snag. It's looking like I'm missing an ESRI CD that has important ArcGIS engine stuff. Does that sound right?

Comment: You'll need to install the ArcObjects Java SDK from the ArcGIS installation media. You'll also probably want to get the latest service pack for both ArcGIS Desktop and the ArcObjects Java SDK from the ESRI site.

Comment: After that you'll want to follow the steps under [Installing ESRI plug-ins](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#/Installing_ESRI_Plug_ins/0001000003v8000000/) (for Eclipse) and then [How to create an add-in project in Eclipse](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#/How_to_create_an_add_in_project_in_Eclipse/0001000003m3000000/). I had never done this before myself but I was able to create a Hello World add-in button without too much fuss. I am using 10.1 but I don't think much changed since 10.0 for Java.